# How to portforward from an IP to another

Tags: java, server, portforwarding

I need to redirect data from one point to another and I'll try to explain as much as possible what I want to do.
Let's say with a specific software I can connect to a local IP address, port 1911. This let me access a controller, I can program and see what's happening on it. What I would like to be able to do first is create a Java program that would be on a computer in the local network. It would "take" all the incoming data from the controller IP address port 1911 and forward it to his IP address with another port. That way, a second computer would be able to connect to the first one to the specific port (the one that forwards) and receive all the data from the controller. Of course it would be good that the program does the exact opposite, from computer to controller.

To say it simply, there would be some sort of "server" in between the controller and the other computer.

At first glance, it seems completely useless, but it's a first step in a bigger project. And I would need your help to get started, that way I hope to be able to do the rest of the project on my own. It's more a sort of exercise before doing the real thing.

thanks you in advance,

Victor

Comment: Not sure why should program retranslate data from controller to same controller, did you mean it will act as proxy between controller and computer?

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent a proxy server ?

Comment: For now the program I described act as a proxy. But this is just for me to know where to start. After that I will modify this program and add complexity to the whole project by having a web server and the controller and computer in two different sub networks protected by a firewall.

Comment: Ok so I've managed to put a proxy on a laptop between the controller and another laptop all in the same network. But now I would the laptop that is in between to not just forward data to one of his local port but directly to a webserver. How can I do that ? 
The reason I want to do this is because the firewall will not allow the webserver to read the port the laptop which has the proxy. I hope I'm clear enough and I'm not saying something stupid. Please let me know what you think.